# Flutter animated BackDropFilter with flutter_staggered_animations

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there any way to aply backdrop filter that is shown with flutter_staggered_animations? Blur effect appears only after animation ends...

Comment: include codes of what you have tried so far

Comment: I basically used stock code of _stagged_animations and edited code of the animated elements with background filter, but no luck.

Comment: Please add it here